# Want to print result and exit from code exection

Tags: php, exit

I need terminate the script and print the JSON with some message. I  have following code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function returnJSON (string $string, bool $success) {
    exit(json_encode(['success' => $success, 'message' => $string])); //doesnt print anything
}

if ($someCondition)
    returnJSON("This message is not printed...", false);

/*some code...*/
```

Script is terminated correctly but it will not print output JSON. But if I remove the function and if I place `exit` into `if statement` everything works great:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if ($someCondition)
    exit(json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => "now everything works... but why?"]));

/*some code...*/
```

Can someone explain it to me? How can I terminate script and print JSON inside function?

EDIT:

Full code:

```
<?php
require("../tridy/SimpleMailer.php");
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function returnJSON (string $string, bool $success) {
    exit(json_encode(['success' => $success, 'message' => $string]));
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']))
    if (strpos('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) !== 0)
        returnJSON("Neplatný HTTP ORIGIN.", false);
else
    returnJSON("Chybí hlavička HTTP ORIGIN.", false);

if (empty($_POST["name"]) || empty($_POST["email"]) || empty($_POST["subject"]) || empty($_POST["message"]) ||
    empty($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) //this condition is true
    returnJSON("Nebyly vyplněny všechny pole.", false);

if (!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    returnJSON("Email není ve správném formátu.", false);

if (strlen($_POST["name"]) > 20 || strlen($_POST["name"]) < 3 || strlen($_POST["subject"]) > 50 || strlen($_POST["subject"]) < 5)
    returnJSON("Pole nesplňují požadavky. Pravděpodobně přesahují maximálaní nebo nesplňují minimální délku.", false);

$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6LcCRVsUAAAAAFMGhWg0Yv9-SMG9OMtFMzKU-ys5&response=".$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if (!json_decode($response)->success)
    returnJSON("Google Recaptcha nebyla ověřena", false);

$mailer = new SimpleMailer();

$body = "Zpráva z kolemzeme.tode.cz!<br><b>Od:</b> ".$_POST["name"];
$body .= "<br><b>Zpráva:</b> ";

$mail->from_name = $_POST["name"]." - Kolem Země cestovat denně";
$mail->to = "email@email.cz";
$mail->subject = $_POST["subject"]." - Zpráva z kolemzeme.tode.cz";
$mail->content_type = "text/html";
$mail->body = $body.htmlspecialchars($_POST["message"]);

if ($mail->send() != 1)
    returnJSON("Je mi líto, ale vznikla nějaká neznámá chyba při odesílání emailu. Prosím zkuste to znovu později.", false);
else
    returnJSON("Email byl úspěšně odeslán. Děkuji za kontaktování, pokusím se ti odpovědět co nejdříve.", true);
```

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to call `exit` in if statement and call `returnJSON` for output JSON, but it still not work:

```
function returnJSON (string $string, bool $success) {
    return(json_encode(['success' => $success, 'message' => $string]));
}

if ($someCondition)
    exit(returnJSON("Still doesn't print anything", false));
```

Now it looks like `json_encode` doesn't return anything but when i test it it does.

Comment: Works for me. I can't replicate.

Comment: Why do you want to replace it with `exit`?

Comment: You sure you enter `returnJSON`?

Comment: @user3783243 I'm sure i do

Comment: Have you set the `$someCondition = true`?

Comment: Seems fine https://3v4l.org/XcLiD

Comment: @Harvey Fletcher Yes, because if i replace function call with exit it works

Comment: Which PHP version? 5.6?

Comment: No, version 7.1

Comment: I will edit post with my full code

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Comment: `if ($mail->send != 1)` I believe `send` is a funcion and you should use `if ($mail->send() != 1)`

Comment: @Felippe Duarte Thanks i will edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour, I finally found the problem. It was: **ENCODING**

When I didn't call function encoding was ok, but when i access to text from function parameter, encoding was bad and `json_encode` was returning empty string. That's why i didn't saw anything but script was terminated.

My final code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

function returnJSON (string $string, bool $success) {
    exit(json_encode(['success' => $success, 'message' => utf8_encode($string)])); //Fixing encoding
}

if ($someCondition)
    returnJSON("Working well with diacritics (ěščřžýáíé)", false);

/*some code...*/
```